# Solving constraint optimization problem with lagrange multipliers

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the objective $$\max_{x,y} x^TAx +y^TBy $$
subject to: $$\|x\|^2 +\|y\|^2 =1 $$

Setting the derivative of the Lagrangian w.r.t to $x$ and $y$ to zero, yields:

$$Ax = \lambda x$$
$$By = \lambda y$$

Is there a possibility to express the solution without using Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Just continue with your calculations: solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $\lambda$ and then put that back in your equality constraint to find $\lambda$, and then substitute in the values for $x$ and $y$ to get the actual maximizers. Are $A$ and $B$ symmetric, positive definite?

Comment: Yes they are only positive definite.

Comment: How do I solve for x. Then I only get an expression $(A - \lambda I)x =0$

Comment: This means that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and that $x$ is one of its associated eigenvectors. This also gives the condition that $A$ and $B$ needs to share, at least, a common eigenvalue or that either $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Comment: So the solutions are the eigenvectors corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of A and B?

Comment: Is this the right answer?

Comment: It is math. Not a random guessing game. You'll have to do the math.

Comment: If I would add the two equalities and rewrite the left hand side as block diagonal matrix, I can argue that multiplying from the left with $(x+y)^T$ on both side yields $\lambda $ on the right side. Therefore the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eingenavalue of this block diagonal matrix is the solution. Is this the right reasoning?

Comment: What happens when you substitute the condition for the derivative to be zero in the cost function?

Comment: I would get $\lambda$, so I have to use the largest common eigenvalue of A and B?

Comment: What happens when there is no eigenvalue in common?

Comment: Then there is no solution?

Comment: Yes, there is. There would be no solution if we would require $x\ne0$ or $y\ne0$.